# Should I use an s3 bucket for my files or should I just stick to my ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I have an aws ec2 instance running and I'm wondering if I really need to use an s3 bucket to store files that users upload or if I should just store the files onto my ec2 instance. Which technqiue is more safe and costs less, etc. Any answer will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Valuable reading: [Treat your servers like cattle, not pets](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/653/what-is-the-definition-of-cattle-not-pets).

You're asking for an opinion, which is not really Stack Overflow's space, but here's an opinion: don't let your EC2 instance be the storage of record for your user's data, regardless of the cost. As it happens, S3 is both extremely cheap and [beyond extremely durable](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/storage-classes/).

Comment: Thanks. I was looking at ec2 pricing and etc and realized they can't store much.

Comment: You can add EBS volumes to increase block storage to EC2 and stripe as needed or even go enterprise-grade with EFS, perhaps backed by storage of record in S3, but S3 should always be your first consideration for individual files (as objects). There are also solutions to help distribute/cache files if needed (CloudFront) and ways to securely provide access to private files in S3 (e.g. pre-signed URLs over an HTTPS connection).

Comment: I'll probably stick to s3 for now then but I'll look into EFS, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Cost part is easy to answer. Safe/secure - to some extent too.

S3 would simply cost you $0.023/Gb per month https://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/ some cheaper options for infrequently accessed data are also available.

If you are sticking with EC2 - your files would be stored in EBS volumes - and the cost would be 0.10/Gb per month. https://aws.amazon.com/ebs/pricing/

So - at least 4x difference here.

That's oversimplified. Ideally, for EC2 you need at least 2 instances with 2 sets of volumes, so - 8x. Add here backups, some headroom for storage... you'll be easily looking at EC2 being 10+x more expensive option.

S3 gives you 11 nines. That's 99.999999999% durability out of the box. Without any extra effort on your side. Good luck doing it yourself with EC2/EBS.